# check specified datagridview cell for numerical value vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, isnumeric

I have a question about datagrids I have a datagridview and want some of the cells to be limited to the use of numbers only and other left to accept whatever text the user wants. The idea I came up with is to use a datagrid cell value change event which checks the specified cell to see if it contains a numeric value if so then continue else show message box and reselcet the incorect cell till it dose contain a number my example however just moves on to the other cell how do I fix this?

```
        MessageBox.Show("Changed")

    Dim HVAL As String
    HVAL = DataGridView2.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value
    If IsNumeric(HVAL) Then
        MsgBox("is number, do nothing")
    Else
        MsgBox("is other than number")
        DataGridView2.Rows(2).Cells(1).Selected = True
        DataGridView2.Rows(2).Cells(1).Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Crimson
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The datagridview has a built in CellValidation event flow for exactly this, so don't invent your own.  To get started look at:
Winforms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ehy30d4(v=vs.110).aspx 
The example there shows the basic setup, come back with specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: This looks like a controll for the entire column I need to validate only specific cells?